# Update tabhost imageView from another activity

Tags: android

I currently have a tabhost with 5 tabs. Over one of the tabs I have an ImageView that when the tabs are created it pulls data via POST to display a number. I am wondering how from one of the tab activities (say Rate.java) I could call that method to update that ImageView that is over one of the tabs.

I know it's not very specific but I think I wrote it so you know what I am talking about.

Let me know if you require anymore info.

talitore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information given, two options that immediately come to mind are:

- Send a broadcast from the tab activity (e.g. Rate.java) and have the activity hosting the ImageView listen for it.
- Create some sort of BaseActivity (extending `Activity`) that takes a custom Listener interface with an update method. Have your tab activities extend that BaseActivity and the activity with your ImageView implement it. You can then call the update method on the listener from your tab activities (instantiate them as a BaseActivity and pass along the listener) and make the activity with the ImageView act upon it.

//Edit per request:

A good starting point for information about broadcasts and receivers is the documentation for the [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). In your case it's probably easiest to just create them in code.

A minimal example will contain something like the following:

**BroadcastSendingActivity:**

```
public class BroadcastSendingActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String UPDATE_IMAGEVIEW = "UPDATE_IMAGEVIEW";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sender);

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(UPDATE_IMAGEVIEW);
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }
```

}

**BroadcastReceivingActivity:**

```
public class BroadcastReceivingActivity extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.receiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver();
    }

    private void registerReceiver() {
        if (mReceiver == null) {
            mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if (intent.getAction().equals(BroadcastSendingActivity.UPDATE_IMAGEVIEW)) {
                        // code to update imageview...
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(BroadcastSendingActivity.UPDATE_IMAGEVIEW));
    }

    private void unregisterReceiver() {
        if (mReceiver != null) {
            getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }
    }
```

}

Note that I did not test the code, but I'm sure you'll be able to figure out any mistakes I might've made. :)

Comment: I will accept your first option as my answer. Would you please elaborate a bit on it? With maybe a link to something easy to implement that you know works? I'll do research on my part. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I've added some code snippets to illustrate the idea. `BroadcastSendingActivity` will send a broadcast upon creation, which will be received by `BroadcastReceivingActivity` (provided it has registered as receiver before the broadcast is sent of course). In your case the tab activities would be senders, and the activity hosting the imageview the receiver.

Comment: Just to verify, I have to add the BroadcastSendingActivity subclasses in my Rate.java and BroadcastReceivingActivity to the activity that has tabhost?

Comment: That's correct, since you want want to inform the activity with the tabhost when it should update the imageview. In other words: your Rate.java should *send* a message ('broadcast') to your activity with the tabhost.